# Error parsing YAML, invalid file "C:\wamp64\www\swapp/translations\date.it.yml"

Tags: symfony, twig, yaml

I'm getting an error with .yml translation file for symfony. Here is my file(date.it.yml).

```
diff.ago.year: un anno fa | %count% anni fa
diff.ago.month: un mese fa | %count% mesi fa
diff.ago.day: %count% giorno fa | %count% giorni fa
diff.ago.hour: un'ora fa | %count% ore fa
diff.ago.minute: 1 minuto fa | %count% minuti fa
```

Think this line gives me error. **un anno fa | %count% anni fa**.

This is my error,

> Error parsing YAML, invalid file
>   "C:\wamp64\www\swapp/translations\date.it.yml"

It would be great if someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using quotes for string values

Comment: it would be great help you can be more specific really sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%` is invalid at the start of a plain string in YAML.

So this line:

```
diff.ago.day: %count% giorno fa | %count% giorni fa
```

is invalid and needs quotes:

```
diff.ago.day: '%count% giorno fa | %count% giorni fa'
```

Now if you had additionally a single quote inside of this string, you would double it. Or you could use double quotes.

May I also recommend my article on strings in YAML for mor information and all kinds of quoting types? It's long, but pretty much complete:
http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2018/03/strings-in-yaml---to-quote-or-not-to-quote.html